# Trying to reset Passwords in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am trying to implement password reset feature in Lumen but could not succeed.

Lumen has access to things like Laravel's **PasswordBroker** and **PasswordManager** but I am not able to use this and succeed. Is there any solution for this.

Comment: What's the error said about? Please be more verbose if you want someone to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I literally just figured this out last night and wrote a blog about it:

http://www.imjohnbon.com/password-resets-in-lumen/

Hopefully it can at least get you on the right track.

Comment: There is so much missing from this link, it is not a solution.

Comment: Very outdated as well. Let me know if you want to update it for Lumen 5.6, I have the solution.

Comment: Bro, just share the solution regardless of demand! @zeros-and-ones

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so I just got this working myself, with Lumen 5.6. (I've upgraded to 5.8, still works, no changes made).

These are the changes I had to make to my code. I had to tweak a few things to suit my system, but this might help someone else.

**Routes**

I wanted two routes.

1. Send reset password email

`GET auth/resetpassword?email=fred@example.com`

2. Reset Password

`PUT auth/resetpassword?token=281...b&username=fred&password=banana&password_confirmation=banana`

**Composer**

To send  the user an email, the following Laravel packages are needed:

```
composer require illuminate/mail "^5.6"
composer require illuminate/notifications "^5.6"
```

**Config files**

Some extra config file are needed:

- config/auth.php
- config/mail.php

I just copied these over from Laravel 5.6, no changes made. I also added the mail variables into my *.env* file.

**bootstrap/app.php**

These new files need to be registered in the app:

```
$app->configure('auth');
$app->configure('mail');

$app->register(Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(\Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);
$app->alias('mailer', \Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer::class);
$app->withFacades();
```

**Database**

I used the default Laravel password_resets table:

```
Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('email')->index();
    $table->string('token');
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
});
```

Now the real changes to the code.

Based on the code from *Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails* and *Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords*.

**AuthController**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    // 1. Send reset password email
    public function generateResetToken(Request $request)
    {
        // Check email address is valid
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);

        // Send password reset to the user with this email address
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
            ? response()->json(true)
            : response()->json(false);
    }

    // 2. Reset Password
    public function resetPassword(Request $request)
    {
        // Check input is valid
        $rules = [
            'token'    => 'required',
            'username' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ];
        $this->validate($request, $rules);

        // Reset the password
        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
        $this->credentials($request),
            function ($user, $password) {
                $user->password = app('hash')->make($password);
                $user->save();
            }
        );

        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
            ? response()->json(true)
            : response()->json(false);
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only('username', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token');
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        $passwordBrokerManager = new PasswordBrokerManager(app());
        return $passwordBrokerManager->broker();
    }
}
```

**User model**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordTrait;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordInterface;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Model implements CanResetPasswordInterface
{
    use CanResetPasswordTrait;
    use Notifiable;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm using Lumen 6x. I installed too composer require ramsey/uuid
Could you share the web.php of how you defined the PUT resetpassword? Thank you

Comment: @GAL hope this helps
`$router->put('resetpassword', ['uses' => AuthController::class . '@resetPassword']);`